# admobfullscreen-codenameone Rewarded ads support

Tags: admob, codenameone

I faced the issue with Rewarded ads, I am using `admobfullscreen-codenameone` library, and issue is in that fact that you can't really detect if user closed the advertisement before timeout, the only suitable callback for that is `onAdClosed()`, which has no parameter and therefore no way to distinguish, was advertisement  watched completely or not.

And this is a big issue for Rewarded ads, because they should be watched till the end otherwise you don't get paid by AdMob, and `admobfullscreen-codenameone` doesn't allow you to detect if user closed advertisement before it was watched completely (I see no other AdMob libraries for CN1), so you can award it with in-app money.

Otherwise user can just close ad after one second and still receive reward, and users will do that once they notice that they get reward anyway.

There is `onAdImpression()` callback in original AdMob listener, and this is what Rewarded ads need, is it possible to receive the same callback in `admobfullscreen-codenameone` ? or may be there some other workaround ?

`admobfullscreen-codenameone` is very good for Interstitial Ads, and I believe it was created for that purpose, but adding `onAdImpression()` callback will make it also very good for Rewarded ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm aware of at least one app that was built with reward ads for Codename One, [this one](https://www.codenameone.com/featured-raffler.html). They used native code to show the ads and published the results as a cn1lib [here](https://github.com/amiga/aerserv-codenameone).

You can probably similarly enhance admob to support such an API with native code.

Comment: thanks for information @Shai, I have android.playService.ads=true hint in codenameone_settings, should I keep it ? or should include Play Services Ads in some other way ?

Comment: This enables the play services support for ads on Android. That means that if someone writes the native code in Android to use the play services ads API it would be available

Comment: yes, I have already implemented native interface for AdMob, works great (although I have used static methods as callbacks from native code), thanks @Shai !